# myODBC mySQL Error with ASP and INT datatypes

Tags: mysql, odbc

I have the following problem, executing a sql query through myodbc to a mysql database.

There is a table calles "tbl_test" with the field "price" where the price is stored in cent. "price" is an INTEGER.

Now I try executing the following query
    SELECT AVG(price) FROM tbl_test

On mysql this query returns the average of the price column. Through myODBC driver, this will result in an error. I found an old bug (from the year 2005) and thought, there must be an update. But I couldn't find any solution for this problem.

Do you have an idea of fixing this (or doing a work around)?

The error shown on the asp page: error '80020009' (not telling very much ...)
Information I found: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14923

Even using "CAST" to an DECIMAL wont work with ODBY :-(

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting same error If you change your query to this:

```
SELECT AVG(price) as avgPrice FROM tbl_test
```

Comment: can you share a simple code you tried? and what is your myodbc version?

Comment: the code sample is:  


    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
    Conn.Open(strConn)  

    strSQL = "SELECT AVG(price) AS avgprice FROM tbl_test"  
    set rsAVG = Conn.Execute(strSQL)  

    if not rsAVG.eof then  
         Response.Write "avg price: " & rsAVG("avgprice")  
    end if